# Pigeonhole Principle: A computer network consists of six computers...

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations, pigeonhole-principle

> A computer network consists of six computers. Each computer is
> directly connected to zero or more of the other computers.
>
> Show that
> there are at least two computers in the network that are directly
> connected to the same number of other computers.

I have figured out that two computers cannot have 0 and 5 connections simultaneously but I cannot go forward from there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can again use contradiction. You already found out that if there is a computer that is not connected to any other then other computers can have at most $4$ connections. If a computer is connected to $5$ computers then there is no computer with $0$ connection.

So you have number of direct connections for each computer between $0$ to $4$ or between $1$ to $5$. These are $5$ numbers but you have $6$ computers. So at least two of them have the same number of direct connections.

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to use the pigeonhole principle here. Suppose we could make each computer have a different number of connections. We represent each computer as a graph vertex and each connection as an edge, so the sum of degrees of vertices is $15$ (as the degree sequence must be $5,4,3,2,1,0$). But this is impossible as the sum of degrees must be *even*, and the statement is proved.

Comment: Could you please elaborate what "the sum of degrees must be even" mean?

Comment: @PrajwalJ This is the handshaking lemma.

Answer (score 1):

We can split this up into two cases:

Case 1: There is a computer with $0$ connections. In this case, the total number of connections for a computer is $0,1,2,3$ or $4$ (since there cannot be one with $5$ connections.). This are five options for six computers and thus, there must be two with the same number of connections.

Case 2: There is a computer with $5$ connections. In this case, the total number of connections for a computer is $1,2,3,4$ or $5$ (since there cannot be one with $0$ connections). This are five options for six computers and thus, there must be two with the same number of connections.

Comment: In the second case did you mean There is *not* a computer with 0 connections.

Comment: Thank you, I have corrected it.